# A principal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\cap_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathfrak{p}^n=(0)$ is minimal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a ring that is not a domain. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A$ such that $\cap_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathfrak{p}^n=(0)$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal, then it is a minimal prime ideal.

How can i prove this result? some ideas will help.

Comment: Where is this coming from?

Comment: i'm not sure, it's an exercise from my class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another, much more elementary proof. You do not even need to assume that $R$ is not a domain (if you are willing to accept the weaker conclusion that $\mathfrak p$ is minimal among the nonzero prime ideals).

Choose a generator $p$ of $\mathfrak p$. Take an arbitrary nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak q\subseteq \mathfrak p$ and a nonzero element $a\in \mathfrak q$. Let $m$ be maximal such that $p^m$ divides $a$ (this exists since $a$ is nonzero, so $a\notin \bigcap_n(p^n)$), so that $a=p^mb$ for some $b\notin (p)$. Then also $b\notin \mathfrak q$ (because $\mathfrak p\supseteq \mathfrak q$), so by primality of $\mathfrak q$, we conclude that $p\in \mathfrak q$, and hence $\mathfrak p\subseteq \mathfrak q$.

Comment: +1 but not sure about "Let $m$ be maximal such that $p^m$ divides $a$." What if e.g. $R = Z[x, z, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_n, ... ] / (x^iy_i = z)$? Then for every $i$, $x^i | z$ but $z$ is not zero. (This can't be the $R$ in the problem but I'm not clear what hypothesis you are using to avoid it.)

Comment: oh of course, you are using the hypothesis that $\bigcap \mathfrak{p}^m = (0)$. Sorry!

Comment: @hunter: yes, exactly. I added a parenthetical remark to make it clear.

Comment: By the way, you mention that one does not "need to assume that $R$ is a domain," but is this even true in a domain? Explicitly, the only minimal prime ideal of a domain is the zero ideal. Of course, in a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m),$ it is true that $\cap_{n \geq 0} I^n = \{0\}$ for every ideal $I$ of $R.$ Combining these two facts, it seems that this is false in a Noetherian local domain: just take a nonzero principal prime ideal.